rsyslog file permissions / New to linux help please
Im useing Ubuntu 22 and useing rsyslog, i have Firewalls, Switches, and Windows , all reporting to my Linux rsyslog.
and i have my logs going into /var/log/test/.../ ... its createing different dir. for each device. and so on.... (so its working so far...
but now i want to use Filezilla, tftp, to go into the folders, and view the log files, but have found the test folder permission wont let me, access denied, so i changed the folder permissions, just to make sure i can grab the files and such.... and its working,  but after rebooting linux, permissions change back.
I edited the rsyslog.conf to use... these options (for example, just to see if i can access the files.
$umask 0000
$FileCreateMode 0775
$DirCreateMode 0775
but i still cant access my log files.
then i tried to use setfacl -m u:syslog:rw /var/log/test/
but nothing is working to set the folders, and file permissions, so i can use TFTP to access the files.
maybe im missing something, been search the web for answers, and examples, and ect... just trying to learn Linux. but something is not right.
Please help. thanks.

Do you run it with sudo?

yes, i use SUDO, to run the setfacl -m command,  / the command is fine, whats not working is getting the permissions to set and stay that way after rebooting.

sudo  filezilla
